# Fail to establish connection for sandbox

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, sandbox

My problem is I followed some instructions online trying to figure out my ip address for the connection for my sandbox. When my virtual machine finalized importing, it popped out window which said that use the ip address 127.0.0.1:8888. This address can't be used directly. So I run `ifconfig` in the bash to figure out the ip, the result was as below

[image]

I tried both 192.160.0.12 and 10.0.3.15 but the page still could not be found. Any ideas about how to establish the connection in the browser? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit vague but I think you are trying to access the hadoop web interface. You need to go to `<ip-address>:50070` to access the web interface

Comment: thanks @Antariksha but my problem is I don't know which IP address I should use. I have updated my question. I have watched some tutorial videos however they only had eth0 not both eth0 and eth1. I am really new to this area and can't figure out what is going wrong here. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: maybe you can find the primary adapter by finding the interface on which the default gateway is on

Comment: Hi @Antariksha i have solved my problem by using the eth1's IP address and opening it in Firefox! Thank you so much!